# Join and merge are only working partially and completely in R

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset that was obtained from a global environment and loaded into R. It has been saved as a CSV and is being read in R as a data frame from that CSV. This dataset (`survey_df`) has almost 3 million entries, I am trying to join this dataset based on a column ID (repeated multiple times since there are multiple entries per id) to what originally was a shapefile and is now loaded in R as a data frame `shapefile_df` . This data frame has 60,000 unique entries, each representing a geometry in a country. We expect to have many entries per geometry in most cases. I am using a simple left_join which should in theory join these two datasets together. I am running into an issue where they are not fully joining together, only some entries are. I have tried inner,fully and right join as well as merge and I keep getting the same issue. I made a full_join and a copy of the id columns to compare the ones that are not joining and I do not see any patterns. They seem to be the same id, they are not joining for some reason. I tried formatting them `as.character` and `as.factor` and yet nothing. Below I pasted a sample of the join/unjoined df.

**Matched ids**

```
| survey_df_id | survey_id_copy | shapefile_df_id
-------------- | --------------  |--------------
0901200010229  | 0901200010229   | 0901200010229
0901500010729  | 0901500010729   | 0901500010729
090050001087A  | 090050001087A   | 090050001087A
0900600010467  | 0900600010467   | 0900600010467
0901400010897  | 0901400010897   | 0901400010897
0901200011960  | 0901200011960   | 0901200011960
```

**Unmatched ids**

```
| survey_df_id | survey_id_copy | shapefile_df_id
-------------- | -------------- |--------------
01903900010480 | 01903900010480 | NA
070470001010A  | NA             | 070470001010A 
0704700010117  | NA             | 0704700010117 
0704700010140  | NA             | 0704700010140 
0705200010672  | NA             | 0705200010672
0705200010742  | NA             | 0705200010742
```

Most of the entries that are unmatched are like the first row where `shapefile_df_id` is NA. However, there are a few where `survey_id_copy` is NA. This field is simply a `mutate` of `survey_df_id` and in theory should not be any different yet they are. Any idea what could be causing this? I suspect this is a formatting issue but as a said, using `as.` hasn't fixed the issue. I am using tidyverse and read.csv. Any help?

Comment: Seems like maybe a leading blank space? Is the data being read in as numeric? Maybe you can force all to numeric.

Comment: @markhogue I just updated it since I realized I didn't include it but unfortunately a good portion of the ids have a letter character in them, usually the last character. Changing to as.numeric makes those with a letter at the end, an NA.

Comment: In your `left_join`, do you include `by = c("survey_df_id", "shapefile_df_id")`? Wondering if a default match gives additional fields not shown.

Comment: Instead of going to numeric, I'd recommend using `trimws` first on the columns and keeping all as `character`.

Comment: Incorrect behavior in left_join() when joining numeric to integer #601. See here: <https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/601>

Comment: @markhogue I do, `by = c("survey_df_id"="shapefile_df_id")` It's such a weird situation, never had anything like this happen before!

Comment: @TarJae Thank you, I am relieved to see it's bug but is there a workaround or fix? Some of the links on the git are broken.

Comment: @ BoniPhila. If this is the cause of the strange behaviour just be sure that both id's are numeric!

Comment: @TarJae The only issue is that there are letter characters in some of the ids so using as.numeric will create NAs for these ids that have them :(